# Java BoxLayout place some Objects left and some right

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, boxlayout

i want to place child components to a `JPanel`. But the problem is, that i want to place the components on the left-hand side and on the right-hand side of the parent `JPanel`. I'am using a `BoxLayout` and currently i have set the X Alignment of the child components. My problem is showed here: [MyProblem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytsy5.png)

Comment: Please share your code in form of [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to achieve what you are looking for.

When using `BoxLayout`, I usually place the components into nested panels.

See my example where I use `BoxLayout` with `X_AXIS` for each component. You could use another [LayoutManagers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) as well, this is just an example:

```
public class BoxLayoutAlign {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            UIManager.put("Label.font", new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 20));
            createGui();
        });
    }

    private static void createGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
        contentPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        frame.setContentPane(contentPanel);

        JLabel left = new JLabel("Left");

        JLabel right = new JLabel("Right");

        JLabel center = new JLabel("Center");

        contentPanel.add(placeLeft(left));
        contentPanel.add(placeRight(right));
        contentPanel.add(placeCenter(center));

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    static JPanel createBoxXWith(Component... components) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        for (Component c : components)
            panel.add(c);
        return panel;
    }

    static JPanel placeRight(Component component) {
        return createBoxXWith(Box.createHorizontalGlue(), component);
    }

    static JPanel placeLeft(Component component) {
        return createBoxXWith(component, Box.createHorizontalGlue());
    }

    static JPanel placeCenter(Component component) {
        return createBoxXWith(Box.createHorizontalGlue(), component, Box.createHorizontalGlue());
    }
}
```

It results to:

[image]

Comment: Hi George,
this solution works! But now i am interrested in how you would do it with nested panels. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: or how you would solve it with other LayoutManagers?

Comment: @Chippi_5 See my method. It uses nested BoxLayout panels. And these panels are added to the parent panel. This is nesting. About other layout manager, see the link. I support `BorderLayout` and `FlowLayout` can achieve it too.

Comment: ok thank you very much!